# Pulling up the whole text body

Tags: spacing, header-footer

[image]

I want to pull up the whole text body nearer to the header so that I can have some spacing below. Please suggest how to do this. I am using the following coding -

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{$\Lambda$-Modules} 
\label{ch:lambda}
\rhead{$\Lambda$-Modules}
\lhead{Chapter \ref{ch:lambda}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `geometry` package.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimum working example (MWE), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
...
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
...
```

and you'll see what length you have to modify.